# Sequence execution in epic

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs

I need to modify an epic in order to call additional action after finishing deletion, the epic
looks like:

```
const deleteComponentEpic: Epic<
  AppActions,
  AppActions,
  AppStore,
  ComponentDetailsEpicsDependencies
> = (action$, _, { components }) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filterAction(deleteComponentAction.request),
    exhaustMap(action =>
      components.deleteComponent(action.payload.id).pipe(
        map(() => deleteComponentAction.success()),
        catchError((error: Error) => of(deleteComponentAction.failure(errorHandler(error)))),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

I need to call following action when deletion went successfully, how to do it? Below is import of my action:

```
import { fetchCategoryComponentList } from '../../store';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no compulsion that you need to have a one-to-one in/out ratio. You can emit multiple actions using mergeMap (aka flatMap) if you need to.
You can do following -

```js
components.deleteComponent(action.payload.id).pipe(
        mergeMap(() => of(deleteComponentAction.success(), fetchCategoryComponentList())),
        catchError((error: Error) => of(deleteComponentAction.failure(errorHandler(error)))),
      ),
```

Read this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40895613/11167389